# Downloading files using Python requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am writing a script to download files from Slack using the slack api and the requests library in Python. Anytime I download a file they all come out the same size (80kb) and they are all corrupted.

Here is my code:

```
def download_file(url, out):
    try:
        os.stat(out)
    except:
        os.mkdir(out)

    local_filename = out + '\\' + url.split('/')[-1]
    print('outputting to file: %s' % local_filename)

    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        response.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw,f)
    return local_filename
```

I have tried various different methods posted throughout SO to download the files but have not been successful. I have also checked the URL's I am getting from the Slack API and they are correct since I can paste them in my browser and download the file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient?

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani I am using the standard web API to make GET requests: https://api.slack.com/web

Comment: Have you tried to download any other images apart from the slack one?

Comment: Can you please paste me any image link that you are going to download?

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani I have not tried to download any other images. I cannot provide a link because the image is coming from a slack channel which I cannot give you access to (but yes I am an admin of the Slack workspace)

Comment: Is the same problem with other images except Slack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Since I am using the image's private url download from the Slack API file object, I needed to include a header in addition to the basic request with a token. To do this using the requests API:

`response = request.get(url,stream = True, headers={'Authorization':'Bearer ' + my_token})`

Comment: I honestly thought the files in the workspace were public as well. I'm a bit surprised Slack does it this way... They charge for stored files that are only private. Bah! Thanks for pointing this out on SO.